# Matching last occurance of character using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match:

```
<p><span style="font-size: 18px;"><strong>Hello</strong></span></p>
```

I need to match the text hello between the last `>` and the first `</`

Using `(?=>)(.*?)(?=</)` returns `<span style="font-size: 18px;"><strong>Hello`

Thanks!

Comment: You should use HTML Agility Pack to parse html instead.

Comment: Do you want the text "Hello" only?

Comment: The last `>` comes after `<span`, just before `</p>` – that's why one shouldn't use regular expressions for parsing HTML

Comment: The text between the last `>` and the first `</` is "`strong></span></p`". Also, please don't parse HTML with regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with

```
/>([^<>]+)</
```

That should give you the desired match.

Comment: Small improvement: `>([^<>]+)<`, now the desired text is in the 1st capture group. http://rubular.com/r/l8Z4oXR0HL

Comment: Oh, I intended to write it like that, it was a typo ^^ Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the answer you were looking for but parsing html with regex is like eating soup with a fork. You'll get the job done eventually but it's very frustrating.

Try this instead and keep your sanity:

```
string html = "<p><span style=\"font-size: 18px;\"><strong>Hello</strong></span></p>";
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(html);
string hello = doc.Descendants().LastOrDefault().Value;
```

Comment: It's not always strong, sometimes it doesn't have strong, only p etc

Comment: @Dimo Added `doc.Descendants().LastOrDefault()` to get the last element

Answer (score 0):

Do you only need to match this specific string? If yes, then you could simply use:

`/<strong>([^<]*)</strong>/`

which will match any text between the `strong` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The constant variable for regex is

```
const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<.*?>";
```

The function

```
 static string StripHTML(string inputString)
        {
            return Regex.Replace
              (inputString, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
        }
```

and call the function like

```
string str = "<p><span style='font-size: 18px;'><strong>Hello</strong></span></p>";

str = StripHTML(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your first `look ahead` must look more like : `(?<=>)` (`look behind` for `>`)

And replace `.*?` by `[^<>]*` (anything but `<` or `>`).

If you need to keep your `look around` you can do : 
`(?<=>)([^<>]*)(?=</)`

If not, you can simply do : `>([^<>]*)</`

The difference is that using `look around` you won't capture `<` neither `</` in the global match.